# firebase email verification web

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I am having issues with my email verification. My error is "user is null" so it doesnt send the verification email, but it does show a log in uid in the console and my console.firebase.google.com project shows the signed up email. What should I change so an email is sent and no access is given until user has verified their email? I've read the docs but cant figure it out. Thank you in advance.

```
//add create user event
btnSignUp.addEventListener('click', e => {
    //get email and Password
    const email = txtEmail.value;
    const pass = txtPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    user.sendEmailVerification();
    promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
});
//Add a realtime listener
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user.emailVerified) {
        console.log('Email is verified');
        console.log(user);
    } else {
        window.location = "index.html";
        firebase.auth().signOut();
        alert("Email is not verified");
    }
```

Comment: alright, thank you. Is there a way to make the user not show up in the google firebase console until they have clicked the verify link in their email?

Answer (score 3):

For the `Firebase version 9`, I am currently using -

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    const user = userCredential.user;

    sendEmailVerification(user)
      .then(() => {
        // Email verification sent!
        let msg = 'An email verification link has been sent to ' + user.email;
        document.querySelector('.success.email_msg').innerHTML=msg;
      });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    document.querySelector('.error.reg_error').innerHTML = error.message;
  });
```

Comment: I do confirm that this code works (v9.6.10) BUT NOT WITH ALL EMAIL ADDRESSES !
I was testing my code with a no-gmail address and even though the Promise still claims it was successful (-then- block is processed), no email has been received. After I've changed  the address to a gmail one, emails started to be really sent (or at least I could find them in the inbox). PS: I was checking Spam box of course, no email received in the no-gmail.
This could be related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52193608/firebase-authentication-emails-sent-but-not-received-on-special-email-addresses

Answer (score 1):

You are not waiting for the promise to resolve. Update to the following snippet:

```
const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
promise.then(user => {
  user.sendEmailVerification();
}).catch(error => console.log);
```