# Firebase Authentication: Emails sent but not received on special email addresses such as *@gmx.at

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, smtp, firebase-authentication

I am using **Firebase Authentication** in my Ionic App. **Some users have reported to not receive the verification email** which is sent after a user signs up, or when the resendVerificationEmail is triggered.

This works fine for email providers like @gmail.com or @live.de, but for those other users with **special providers like @gmx.at it's not working**. The emails are sent successfully according to firebase but they are never received.

Possibly the emails get filtered?
Has anyone else ran into this problem? The message template can not be modified but would using a custom SMTP server possibly help?

Comment: Did you find out the cause of the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved by using my own private SMTP server for sending the Authentication emails.

I am using a hosting service for my domain that comes with email service so I am using that one. Using other services such as Mailgun or Mailjet etc. might also solve the problem.

You can set up your custom SMTP server right in the firebase console under Authentication/Templates.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with others emails providers (orange.fr sfr.fr free.fr ...). After deeper analysis, it appeared that it is the domain address inside the (generated) link that is detected as SPAM by emails providers (maybe everything that sounds like  *.firebaseapp.com)

https://your-subdomain.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action...

I changed it to a custom one of mine (through Authentication->templates->"Customize action URL" (bottom right)):

https://www.my-custom-domain.com/__/auth/action

and no more problem!

Some doc (note on blue background):
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler?hl=en&authuser=0#link_to_your_custom_handler_in_your_email_templates

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem, solved by combining the two DNS TXT SPF records

Firebase and my email provider

From

> "v=spf1 include:spf.tutanota.de -all"

> "v=spf1 include:_spf.firebasemail.com -all"

To

> "v=spf1 include:_spf.firebasemail.com include:spf.tutanota.de ~all"

Check https://serverfault.com/questions/845218/combining-multiple-spf-records